# How to run hibernate+spring mvc on both oracle and mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My aim is to run a spring+hibernate application on Oracle XE and MySQL database. I don't want to change my Entity model, I just want to change database connection in XML and it should run on both MySQL and Oracle.

**MySql Config in xml :**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
...
<property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
...
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_mysql_db?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root123" />
</bean>
```

**Oracle config in xml**

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
...
<property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">mdsinstance</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">admin123</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">mdsinstance</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
...
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="mdsinstance" />
    <property name="password" value="admin123" />
</bean>
```

**Hibernate Enity pojo(for both mysql and oracle) :**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "t_customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private int customerId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "customer_creation_date")
private Date customerCreationDate;

@Column(name = "customer_color_code")
private String customerColorCode;

@Lob              //if used it give error in mysql as it takes longtext instead of text
@Column(name = "customer_responsible_user",columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String customerResponsibleUser;

@Column(name = "customer_is_active",columnDefinition = "TINYINT")  // gives error for oracle as tinyint not supportrd in oracle
private String customerIsActive;

@Column(name = "customer_setting",columnDefinition = "JSON")  //gives error as json not supported in oracle
private String customerSetting;
}
```

As you see my entity model is same for both oracle and mysql database.If i use **@Lob** then it give error in mysql **"expects longtext but found text"** as in mysql table the column type is text.Similarly how to manage tinyint and json types of mysql into oracle with same entity pojo.

Comment: The `@Column` attributes bind it to a particular database because of the `columnDefinition`. If you want your entity to be portable use shared values or use another way of managing your database (you shouldn't use hibernate to manage your DB schema in the first place!).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you very much for guidance, can you please share few resources online which I could follow, will hbm.mapping.xml separately for Oracle and MySQL will help? or is there alternate ways instead of using columnDefintion as I feel its not best practice!

Comment: You don't want duplicate/different mappings per database. Don't specify the columns but use something like flyway/liquibase to manage your database. For testing, if really needed, you can just use H2 and automatic schema generation.

Comment: it's not duplicate mapping, the column types will be different in different hbm.mapping.xml for Oracle and mysql.I am using automatic schema generation from hibernate i.e <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> .But if columndefinotion="tinyint" , it will create table with column tinyint in mysql which will work fine but it creates table in oracle with tinyint too,this will not work will it?

Comment: Don't use automatic schema creation from hibernate, even the hibernate team advices against using that for your live system!.